# Solving a complicated matrix problem in excel

Tags: excel, algorithm

First time asking for advice here so I apologize if my terminology is messed up.

Here is what I'm trying to figure out how to solve (ideally in excel):

Given I can have up to **5 groups (A)**, and each group could have up to **4 entries (B)**, how do I evenly distribute **B** where the **sum always equals 100.**

**Example 1:**

```
Group A1 - Entry B1 = 15
Group A1 - Entry B2 = 15
Group A1 - Entry B3 = 15
Group A1 - Entry B4 = 15
-----
Group A2 - Entry B5 = 20
Group A2 - Entry B6 = 20
SUM OF B1:B6 = 100
```

**Example 2:**

```
Group A1 - Entry B1 = 25
Group A1 - Entry B2 = 25
----- <br/>
Group A2 - Entry B3 = 50
SUM OF B1:B3 = 100
```

**Example 3:**

```
Group A1 - Entry B1 = ???
Group A1 - Entry B2 = ???
Group A1 - Entry B3 = ???
----- <br/>
Group A2 - Entry B4 = ???
----- <br/>
Group A3 - Entry B5 = ???
Group A3 - Entry B6 = ???
SUM OF B1:B6 = 100
```

Comment: 100 divided by the number of entries? You don't explain why some entries have larger values than others, so it's hard to provided anything really useful... This looks like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: If you can explain why group a can't be all 17 and group b 16, in your first example we may be able to help.  As is this is too broad a task for this site.

Comment: Example 1: Group A1 has a weighting score of 60% and Group A2 40%.  So each group A could have different weightings, and each group could have up to 4 entries

Comment: Ok, Why? Why does group A get 60% and Group B get 40%?  is that set by the user?  If so just divide the allocation by the number in the group.

Comment: @ScottCraner - yes it's set by the user.  in example 3, group a1 has a 50% weighting and three metrics, group A2 has a 35% weighting and only one metric, and group A3 has a weighting of 15% and 2 metrics...

Comment: Then the answer would be A1: 16.666667, A2: 35, and A3: 7.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your allocation in a table that can be referenced use this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,D:E,2,FALSE)*100/COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

Where your allocation table is in Columns D and E.

[image]

Comment: Okay to expand on that solution, if column C was a score between 1 and 5, 5 being the highest, how would you represent the total score based on the weighting in column B?

Comment: @BarryTallis  Stack Overflow policy is one question per post.  Please post a new question with the new criteria. Please show in tabular form what you have and what you want.